# What is the size of memory in this diagram?

Tags: memory, operating-system

I want to ask some questions about this diagram that showing the main memory with OS and different processes : how can I compute the size of main memory in Kbytes ? and What will happen if Process B generates a logical address of 200? Will the CPU return a
physical address or error?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd assume the unlabeled numbers on the left are addresses in bytes; which would imply there's 2048 bytes (or 2 KiB) of something (virtual space, or physical space, or maybe even RAM if there's no devices mapped into the physical space). Of course it could just as easily be 2048 bits, or 2048 (36-bit) words, or..

If Process B tries to access logical address of 200; it might work (no security), or it might cause some kind of trap/exception because the process doesn't have permission to access the operating system's area; or it could be impossible for the process to do that (e.g. maybe the design of the CPU restricts the process to unsigned offsets from a base address of 1203).